# Сравнить два файла по одинаковым фрагментам и поместить их в третий файл

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Нужно написать программу, что сравнивает два текстовых файла и помещает однаковые фрагменты в третий файл.
Изначально озадачился словом "фрагмент". Я спросил у преподавателя, что имееться ввиду. Мне ответили что одинакоый фрагмент это последовательность символ совпадающая по позиции в файлах. Но, честно говоря я все равно не совсем понял. Допустим у меня есть две строки, у первой содержимое первого файла, у второй - второго соотвественно. Но как именно мне сравнивать это сроки, честно говоря, не понятно...

Comment: Это самое примитивное сравнение, которое только можно придумать, на практике почти бесполезное. Чтобы сравнить - глянь на **Meld** (софт), например. Тебе просто нужно прочесать два файла посимвольно, и копировать каждый симол (либо слово, это уже уточняй у препода, но раз сказали символ, то не усложняй себе задачу =)), который совпал, в третий файл.

Comment: Да, если под виндой, то сохраняй файлик в CP1251 и читай через `std::wifstream` (`std::basic_ifstream<wchar_t>`).